# Sort list by name, date and hierarchy

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I want to sort the following list in the following order:

1. first by object without any parent
2. then by name
3. by year
4. by month
5. related objects should come directly after by the criteria (2-4).

So what I want to achieve is basically a tree structure as a flat list.

This is what I've come up with until now, but can't figure out how to implement the parent relation.

```
function monthYearCheck(a, b) {
    if(a.year < b.year) {
        return -1;
    } else if(a.year > b.year) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if(a.month < b.month) {
            return -1;
        } else if(a.month > b.month) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

var sortedArray = nonSortedArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    if(a.name === b.name) {
        return monthYearCheck(a, b);
    } else if(a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
    } else if(a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

This is the array before sorting:

```
[{
    name: "Bottom",
    id: 4,
    parentId: 54,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 16       
},{
    name: "Topp",
    id: 12,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 24
},{
    name: "Middle",
    id: 54,
    parentId: 12,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 14   
},{
    name: "Middle2",
    id: 118,
    parentId: 104,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 4    
},{
    name: "Bottom2",
    id: 5,
    parentId: 54,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 12
},{
    name: "Topp",
    id: 12,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 12
},{
    name: "Middle",
    id: 54,
    parentId: 12,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 4    
},{
    name: "Topp2",
    id: 104,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 12
},{
    name: "Bottom2",
    id: 5,
    parentId: 54,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 2        
}]
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
[{
    name: "Topp",
    id: 12,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 12
},{
    name: "Topp",
    id: 12,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 24
},{
    name: "Middle",
    id: 54,
    parentId: 12,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 14   
},{
    name: "Middle",
    id: 54,
    parentId: 12,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 4    
},{
    name: "Bottom",
    id: 4,
    parentId: 54,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 16       
},{
    name: "Bottom2",
    id: 5,
    parentId: 54,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 2        
},{
    name: "Bottom2",
    id: 5,
    parentId: 54,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 12
},{
    name: "Topp2",
    id: 104,
    month: 5,
    year: 2016,
    value: 12
},{
    name: "Middle2",
    id: 118,
    parentId: 104,
    month: 6,
    year: 2016,
    value: 4    
}]
```

Comment: if(a.parentId&&b.parentId) theothersorting() else if(a.parentId) return 1 else -1;

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?  I added the check, but it doesn't give me the wanted effect.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a tree structure for getting the dependencies and then the ordered result.

```js
var data = [{ name: "Bottom", id: 4, parentId: 54, month: 6, year: 2016, value: 16 }, { name: "Topp", id: 12, month: 6, year: 2016, value: 24 }, { name: "Middle", id: 54, parentId: 12, month: 5, year: 2016, value: 14 }, { name: "Middle2", id: 118, parentId: 104, month: 6, year: 2016, value: 4 }, { name: "Bottom2", id: 5, parentId: 54, month: 5, year: 2016, value: 12 }, { name: "Topp", id: 12, month: 5, year: 2016, value: 12 }, { name: "Middle", id: 54, parentId: 12, month: 6, year: 2016, value: 4 }, { name: "Topp2", id: 104, month: 5, year: 2016, value: 12 }, { name: "Bottom2", id: 5, parentId: 54, month: 6, year: 2016, value: 2 }]
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.year - b.year || a.month - b.month;
    }),
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [],
            o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var temp = { data: [a], children: o[a.id] && o[a.id].children };
            if (o[a.id] && o[a.id].data) {
                o[a.id].data.push(a);
                return;
            }
            o[a.id] = temp;
            if (a.parentId === root) {
                r.push(temp);
            } else {
                o[a.parentId] = o[a.parentId] || {};
                o[a.parentId].children = o[a.parentId].children || [];
                o[a.parentId].children.push(temp);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, undefined),
    result = function getValue(array) {
        return array.reduce(function (r, o) {
            return r.concat(o.data, getValue(o.children || []));
        }, []);
    }(tree);

console.log(result);
console.log(tree); // just how it works ...
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var sortedArray = nonSortedArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return compareParentID(a.parentId, b.parentID) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.year.localeCompare(b.year) || a.month.localeCompare(b.month);
});

function compareParentID(a, b) {
    if (a == null && b != null) 
        return -1;

    if (a != null && b == null) 
        return 1;

    return a - b;
}
```

If the name elements are not equal then it sorts them by the name.

This compares each column. If the name elements are equal, then it goes on to compare the year elements, etc.

Just chain more `||` clauses for each extra element you want to compare, in the order you want to compare them in.

Comment: How is this solving my issue with sorting the children after the parent? Also beware of using localCompare, it's very slow on larger datasets.

Comment: @Victor If localeCompare is too inefficient for you then feel free to write your own comparators. My initial answer was to give you an idea of how to solve the problem. However since it wasn't clear enough, I've provided the complete answer above.

Comment: Hi @Victor if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.